# jquery click on map area doesn't work in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, click, area, internet-explorer-11

So clicking on an area from jquery doesn't work in IE11. Works in Chrome. How can I make it so that IE will trigger when I click on the selected area on the image?

HTML:

```
<img src="http://www.free-pet-wallpapers.com/free-pet-wallpapers/free-pet-desktop-backgrounds/873826831.jpg" usemap="#map" />
<map name="map">
    <area shape="rect" coords="25,25,75,75" href='#asd' />
</map>
```

jQuery:

```
$('area').on('click', function(){ alert('click'); })
```

jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/yUaHG/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know jquery but if it uses onclick in area tag then it's a bug in IE11. I reported it immediately as IE11 preview was released b  https://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/791499/onclick-doesnt-work-in-area-tag-on-ie11
At least for me workaround is to put javascript code in 'href'.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug in `jquery 2.0.2` because works here using jquery 2.x (edge):

http://jsfiddle.net/yUaHG/3/

Comment: Tested with 2.x, 2.0 and 1.9.1, it won't run the `alert`. (IE11 sry, not IE10)

Comment: But at least now it works for me in IE10... Is IE11 already in stable version??? BTW, if you are using IE11, why are you in your question talking about IE10?

Comment: Ok, but it is a preview, what do you expect about a preview, to be stable? Wait MS team to fix bug firstly